# Perceptron - MatLab Serious Confusion

Tags: matlab, neural-network, perceptron

This is my first stab at machine learning, and I can implement the code anyway that I want.  I have Matlab access, which I think will be simpler than Python, and I have pseudo code for implementing a PLA. The last part of the code, however, absolutely baffles me, though it is simpler than the code I have seen on here thus far. It seems to be calling for the use of variables not declared.  Here's what I have.  I'll point out the number line at which I get stuck.

```
1) w <- (n + 1) X m (matrix of small random nums)
2) I <- I augmented with col. of 1s
3) for 1 = 1 to 1000
4)    delta_W = (N + 1) X m (matrix of zeros) // weight changes
5)    for each pattern 1 <= j <= p
6)        Oj = (Ij * w) > 0 // j's are subscript/vector matrix product w/ threshold
7)        Dj = = Tj - Oj // diff. between target and actual
8)        w = w + Ij(transpose)*Dj // the learning rule
```

Lines 1 thru 4 are coded. 
My questions are on line 5: What does "for each pattern mean" (i.e., how does one say it in code). Also, which j are they interested in, I have a j in the observation matrix and a j in the target matrix. Also, where did "p" come from (I have i's, j's, m's and n's but no p's)?  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"for each pattern" refers to the inputs. All they are saying is to run that loop where Ij is the input to the perceptron.

To write this in MATLAB, it really depends on how your data is oriented. I would store your inputs as a mXn matrix, where m is the number of inputs and n is the size of each input.

Say our inputs look like :

```
input = [1 5 -1;
         2 3 2;
         4 5 6;
         ...    ]
```

First 'augment' this with a column of ones for the bias input:

```
[r c] = size(input);
input = [input ones(r,1)];
```

Then, your for loop will simply be:

```
for inputNumber = 1:r
    pattern = input(inputNumber,:);
```

and you can continue from there.

Comment: Thank you! Thant's definitely a start and, also, more food for thought as to how to interact with Matlab. It look very straight-forward and then, well, it didn't. Once again, thanks for the english translation of that line!